# No suitable driver found sqllite. IntelIj ultimate drivers

Tags: java, sqlite

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate. I try to connect to an existing db that I created by using creator.

I have installed driver and I get these errors:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:421)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:412)
    at Main.main(Main.java:8)
No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite:identifier.sqlite
```

As for code I tried to compile:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try { Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC").newInstance(); } catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();};
        Connection connection = null;
        try
        {
            // create a database connection
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:identifier.sqlite");
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            statement.setQueryTimeout(30);  // set timeout to 30 sec.

        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            // if the error message is "out of memory",
            // it probably means no database file is found
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                if(connection != null)
                    connection.close();
            }
            catch(SQLException e)
            {
                // connection close failed.
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error makes clear that you do not have the SQLite JDBC driver on your classpath (or it is the wrong driver class name), and if this is a JDBC 4 or higher JDBC driver, you don't even need to explicitly load the JDBC driver, automatic driver loading will take care of it (and calling `newInstance()` has never been necessary).

Comment: Hello, what's the project type of it? Does it is an IDEA build project or Gradle/Maven? Please share the project structure/screenshot.